# Does Python support multithread in Webpage

Tags: python, multithreading

I am going to setup Python Web Server using CherryPy. When a user submit a form to Python. I want to create another thread inside the webpage being called. Is that possible?

As I have tried pthread in PHP before, and seems pthread not work in webpage. So I want to make clear that Python support multi thread in webpage before I dive in.

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you wants ! Do you want to run some task in another thread or you just ask if CherryPy treat every new request in a new thread ?

Comment: Sorry for my not clear expression. Actually I just want to run some task in another thread and is that possible in Python webpage?

Answer (score 0):

Python is not good for threading, I don't know exactly your needs but I advise to take a look at **[Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org)** a distributed task queu, with it you can runs tasks.

If you don't find Celery useful, May be you need to use **[multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html)** it's a good solution to run tasks in parallel. But you should know that you will be limited with number of processor cores